# AVSpeechSynthesizer speaks, when runs again, takes 10 or so seconds before start

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avspeechsynthesizer

When I run this code, it runs fine, but when 
I run it again, it takes about 10 or so seconds before it runs and that too also gets cut off sometimes.

Edit: Below I have added more code to give a better idea of where the code is being executed. The main thread in this case would be the actual Siri UI. This is a code that is being executed on a jailbroken device. It allows me to have Siri reply in the Hindi language for my parents who do not comprehend English well...

```
- (BOOL)handleSpeech:(NSString *)text withTokens:(NSSet *)tokens withSession:(id<APSiriSession>)session {
  if ([tokens containsObject:@"siri"]) {
  NSRegularExpression *queryRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:.*)Siri ?(.*)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
  NSArray *arrayOfAllMatches = [queryRegex matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];

  NSString *query = nil;
  for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in arrayOfAllMatches) {
      if (match.numberOfRanges > 1) {
          query = [text substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
      }
  }

  if (!query || query.length == 0) {
      query = @"";
  }
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
  [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:8.0];
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
  [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.salmanburhan.com/Siri/Hindi/?input=%@", [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
      NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

         NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:string];
         utterance.rate = 0.1000;
         utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"hi-IN"];
         AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
        [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
        //[synthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryWord];


      [session sendTextSnippet:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] temporary:NO scrollToTop:NO dialogPhase:@"Summary"];

  } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      [session sendTextSnippet:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"An Error Occurred, Sorry.\n\n%@", error] temporary:NO scrollToTop:NO dialogPhase:@"Error"];
      [session sendRequestCompleted];
  }];

  return YES;
  }
return NO;
}
```

Comment: no use, tried that just now. @Zero

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the code? Whenever you see "takes n seconds to start" in iOS you are often dealing with a main thread issue.

All UI work must be on the main thread, all 'expensive' non-UI work must not be on the main thread. Here's a code snippet I copied from http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks#mainthread - which is wonderful blog which you should read.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // switch to a background thread and perform your expensive operation

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // switch back to the main thread to update your UI

    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, So I placed the code where you put //switch to a background thread... And it did the same thing, It ran once, and gave me issues again. I don't think I'd have to place it in the main thread because it is playing sound.

Comment: show us more code, where are you calling your fragment from? (Edit the question, don't put it here in the comment.)

Comment: The   [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:8.0]; line is interesting since that's amount of the delay you are seeing. Wish I could help more.

Comment: I could try removing that, but I mainly added that because sometimes the request would lag and the server would take long to respond with the translated response. But I don't need that anymore because I pre translate the responses so it's almost an instant response... I'll take that out and try, though I doubt that would be the cause.